# Limit Point Definition in Topology

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

For my undergrad real analysis class we are using a book called Principals of Mathematical Analysis and it has a chapter on Topology.  However, I'm pretty confused on what a limit point is. It says "A point p is a limit point of the set E if every neighborhood of p contains a point q $\neq$ p such that q $\in$ E"  But doesn't P only have one neighborhood?  Can anyone offer me an intuitive explanation of what a limit point it? Thanks!

Comment: We can essentially say that a limit point is a point taht all other point "approximate" around.

Comment: Knowing the definitions of the words in the definition is a good starting point. No, in general $p$ need not have only one neighborhood. Also, please properly format your posts in $\LaTeX$

Comment: No, for example, take the point 0 on the real line with the usual topology. All the sets $(-1,1), (-1, \infty), (-10,{1 \over 2})$, etc, are neighbourhoods of 0.

Answer (score 1):

The neighborhoods of a point $p$ are all the sets $F$ containing an open set $U$ containing $p$. So, no, $p$ has many neighborhoods, uncountably many in most examples. For this definition it's enough to take open neighborhoods: $p$ is a limit point of $E$ if every open set $U$ containing $p$ also contains a point $q\neq p$ in $E$. For further intuition, on the real line you can take the sets $U$ to be just $(p-1/n,p+1/n)$ as $n$ runs from $1$ to $\infty$: then the definition says that there are points of $E$, *other than $p$*, arbitrarily close to $p$. And that's how you should think about neighborhoods in general.

Comment: so is every r such that r > 0 and r is small enough to stay within the set a different neighborhood?

Comment: Each such $r$ gives a (potentially) different neighborhood, consisting of those points within $r$ of $p$.

Answer (score 0):

Points in a topological space can have many neighborhoods, even uncountably many.  If $p$ is a limit point of $E$ then every neighborhood of $p$ contains some point in $E$ that is distinct from $p$ (note $p$ need not even be an element of $E$ to be a limit point). To illustrate this consider the interval $(0,1)$.  Which points in $\mathbb{R}$ have neighborhoods (open intervals) that always contain some point in $(0,1)$?

Comment: well wouldn't the interval [0, 1] always contain some point in (0, 1) since r > 0. but couldn't, say, 1.5 be a limit point too if r = ,say, 1.

Comment: You are right with the interval $[0,1]$ but what is $r$?  Is the concept making more sense?

Comment: well this answer is resonating most with me but I'm still a little confused, from my edit above, couldn't  1.5 be a limit point too if r = ,say, 1.  Is there any restriction on what r can be?

Comment: Please be more clear about what $r$ is.  Are you taking about the radius of a ball?  If $p$ is a limit point of $(0,1)$ then every ball containing $p$ must contain some point of $(0,1)$ that is not $p$ itself.  So $1.5$ cannot be a limit point of $(0,1)$ since $B_{\frac{1}{3}}(1.5)$ doesn't contain any point of $(0,1)$.

Comment: r is from the definition of neighborhood: A neighborhood of p is a set $N_{r}(p)& consisting of all q such that d(p, q) < r, for some r >0.  d(p, q) is the metric.

Comment: Is it making sense now?  Just so you are aware, neighborhood in general can just mean an open set, so it need not be an open ball.  The material you're covering is the topology of metric spaces, but there are much broader topologies that exist in other spaces, and neighborhoods in the general context need not be balls, or even defined by a radius.